# How to choose a limit for the epsilon delta proof?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

The epsilon delta proof allows us to prove that a 'given' limit is actually **the limit**. In the sense that, we can show using that if a limit for a sequence/ function exist, then that limit is a unique one. But, how does one find a limit following the epsilon delta definition or do we need something more?

Comment: FYI: Eventually, you'll learn about [Cauchy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence), where what matters is that terms get arbitrarily-close *to each other* (roughly speaking ) rather than arbitrarily-close *to a predetermined value $L$*. In appropriate contexts, this is enough to ensure convergence to a limit without having to know the limiting value ahead of time.

Comment: Mmm I have. But that is only in complete metric space. Good point.

Comment: "complete metric space" = "appropriate context". :)

Comment: Your question seems to boil down to "How do you compute limits?" (as "finding the $L$" in an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof is precisely the task of computing the limit).  This is an incredibly broad question.  I don't see how it can be reasonably answered---even the accepted answer her only gives very vague advice.

Comment: Someone else pointed out that perhaps you mean only to ask about the kinds of functions which might occur in an introductory calculus / analysis class, in the section of the text in which limits are introduced.  If that is the case, please edit the question to add that context.

Comment: I mean my doubt is if on the most basic level if it possible for any procedure to exist for which can ascertain the limit to be used for epsilon delta proof because we only know our guess is valid once we prove it through epsilon delta. @Xander Henderson

Comment: There are many techniques for computing limits, and many theorems about limits.  Generally, we use those theorems and techniques, and are taught to use them in analysis classes.  But there is not (nor can there be) a technique which will allow you to compute every possible limit.

Comment: It is also worth noting, contrary to the impression given in your question, that epsilon-delta arguments are generally not needed for computing sequential limits (those limits are typically phrased in terms of epsilon-$N$ arguments).  epsilon-delta arguments are required for computing limits in places where sequential limits aren't "good enough" (all results in $\mathbb{R}$ can be phrased in terms of sequential limits; this is not true in more general metric spaces).

Comment: I guess this issue is worse when the deftn is introduced in apploed classes than in pure math classes. It's unclear how without using additional theorem one can find the limit. For example it is not even clear why direct substitution of limit should give the thing we expect in epsilon delta limit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the limit. Sometimes, it's obvious and you can just eyeball it. Sometimes, you have to multiply and divide by the relevant quantity in order for it to become obvious. Sometimes, you have to just look at the graph to get a sense of what the limit is.

Sometimes, you actually may have to apply formulas or theorems which are not necessarily applicable just to have an answer to work with. Keep in mind that theorems have conditions and if the conditions are not satisfied by whatever it is that you're dealing with, then you cannot use that theorem. You either have to do something else or you have to modify the thing you're dealing with sufficiently to apply the theorem.

But there's no law that tells you that you can't just sneakily cheat and apply a theorem where it may not be applicable just to get a sense of what the limit is. There's no law that's telling you that you can't just approximate functions by their Taylor expansions and just use that to get a rough estimate for what the limit is.

All of this can be done on scrap paper and, so to speak, is hidden away from public view. We don't publicly tell everyone that we found a limit by L'Hopital's rule. We just tell them what the limit is and prove that it is the limit via the golden standards of proof-writing, whether it be by an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument or by making use of other theorems (by the way, making use of theorems to prove a limit where it is justified is perfectly rigorous.)

Comment: With a good number of math problems, there is an element of guessing going on. The goal is to gain enough experience so that the guessing game becomes a lot more organized and the eventual goal is to become as systematic as you can be.

Comment: Some teachers will present a neat, polished proof and give the students no idea at how it was obtained.  I try to avoid this and allow my students to see my guesses and false starts.  I just have to hope that I get there before I run out of time.

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern: Although many students may do it wrongly, using asymptotic expansion **can** be done completely **rigorously**. Just look at the relevant links from my profile, which also explain roughly how to do it **systematically**. Properly programmed CASes like Maple use asymptotic expansions to compute limits as well.