# How does one compute points which a sequence converges to in a general topological space?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

> A sequence $x_1,x_2, \dots $ of points in a space $X$ converges to a point $x \in X$, if for each neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq N :~ x_n \in U$  [(related)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499042/how-to-choose-a-limit-for-the-epsilon-delta-proof)

I am very confused on how to find converging points to apply this definition. Suppose we are in a general topological space then how can we find the converging point of a sequence? It is unclear to me how one can do it and I can't seem to find in any place the general method to do it.

**Currently, it seems to me that there is no general recipe which you feed in the properties of the topological space and it tells you the limits of the sequences. If this is the case, what are some general tips for finding limits given a specific topology? What properties are the ones which should be focused on generally?**

Comment: In total generality there isn’t any one description of what the space looks like. Maybe provide some example problems, thought experiments in “weird” spaces (eg the long line, a cocountable space...)

Comment: Remember that the same question when $X$ was $\mathbb{R}$ wasn't easy either and while the functions for which you solved it form a fairly rich collection, they were not too wild either. It not only information on $x_n$ is not give, but also on $X$, the question has less of an answer.

Comment: I think the thing of primary importance is the topology you choose. For instance, if on the set $M$ one chooses the chaotic topology, $\{\emptyset,M\}$, then every sequence will converge to every point in $M$. If, however, you choose the discrete topology, $\{\mathcal{P}(M),M\}$, then only the constant sequences will converge. Deciding exactly what point in a topological space a given sequence converges to is going to entirely depend on the specifics of the space.